# (Yup) how to create multiple errors using a single .test() function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

EDIT: while the accepted solution worked, [this](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/176#issuecomment-367352042) worked much better in my use case

I have one function that validates that neither **input field A** nor **input field B** are empty
and with the way my form is built I have to write only one function to check both. (The actual function is much more complicated so I opted to create the example function below)

this is my test function:

```
function isValid(message) {
    //I don't use the message variable but I added it anyway
    return this.test("isValid", message, function (value) {
    if(!value.A) {
        return createError({path: `${this.path}.A`, message:"A is empty"});
    }
    if(!value.B) {
        return createError({path: `${this.path}.B`, message:"B is empty"});
    }
    return true;
    })
```

The result of this is that **when A and B are empty I return the first createError so the rest of the function is skipped** and this is what the **formik.errors** object looks like:

```
{
    parent: {
        A: "A is empty"
    }
}
```

**How do I create an array of errors and return it instead?**

I tried:

returning an array of createErrors() but I got the same result,

using createErrors with an array of paths and messages but the formik.errors looked like this:

```
{
    parent.A: { parent.B: "2 errors occured" }
}
```

instead of **the desired**:

```
{
    parent: {
        a: "A is empty",
        b: "B is empty"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `ValidationError` from `Yup` to achieve this goal. The constructor of `ValidationError` [accepts](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/ceca307e74c5b785c52897c06d1d3c1026513176/src/ValidationError.ts#L37) array of other `ValidationError` instances. The individual `ValidationError` instances are capable of holding `path` and error message and the parent instance will [combine them](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/ceca307e74c5b785c52897c06d1d3c1026513176/src/ValidationError.ts#L52-L54).

Here's the example test function:

```js
import { ValidationError } from 'yup'

const testFunc = (value) => {
    const keys = ['A', 'B']

    const errors = keys.map((key) => {
        if (value[key]) { return null } // Successful validation, no error

        return new ValidationError(
          `${key} is empty`,
          value[key],
          key
        )
    }).filter(Boolean)

    if (errors.length === 0) { return true }

    return new ValidationError(errors)
}
```

It is also possible to do the same thing with `createError` judging by [the source code](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/ceca307e74c5b785c52897c06d1d3c1026513176/src/util/createValidation.ts#L114).

You can pass a function instead of a string to `message` property of `createError` call. In this case the function would be called within `createError` => `ValidationError.formatError` [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/ceca307e74c5b785c52897c06d1d3c1026513176/src/ValidationError.ts#L27). And if this function returned an array of the properly built `VaildationError` instances we would get the same result.

Here's an example test function for that approach:

```js
import { ValidationError } from 'yup'

const testFunc = (value, { createError }) => {
    const keys = ['A', 'B']

    const errors = keys.map((key) => {
        if (value[key]) { return null } // Successful validation, no error

        return new ValidationError(
          `${key} is empty`,
          value[key],
          key
        )
    }).filter(Boolean)

    if (errors.length === 0) { return true }

    return createError({
      message: () => errors
    })
}
```

Comment: Both approaches work great! But for some reason they both include an extra empty error when any error is returned, like: `[undefined, "My error message"]`. Weird because the `errors.length` is `1` 

Comment: I think it's because the first entry on my array has no errors, that's why it was `undefined`.